# Homebrew build with different arch?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

I tried to install mysql-connector-c recipe via homebrew, and it builds just fine, but produces x86_64 library:

```
  $file ~/brew/lib/libmysql.dylib 
  .../brew/lib/libmysql.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I however need i386 library for my project. I tried to give it CFLAGS and LDFLAGS like this:

```
  CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" brew install mysql-connector-c
```

but nothing changes - it still builds x86_64 only binary. Is there any way to make homebrew build either dual arch library or i386 library? I have kernel architecture set to x86_64, if it matters.

Comment: which version of mac you are using? I can't make it work on my Mac 10.8.1. Could you paste your modified brew script here as reference? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
brew edit mysql-connector-c
```

and then modify the initialization in the "install" block.

Although I did not try this out, you are supposed to do something like this:

```
ENV['CFLAGS']='xxx'
ENV['LDFLAGS']='xxx'
```

You might check the example here: [Problems with homebrew, can't install anything...](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/274697-problems-with-homebrew-cant-install-anything/)

Comment: So what would I put there? CFLAGS definitions?

Comment: The given link says : `ENV['CFLAGS']=ENV['CXXFLAGS']="-arch i386"`. i386 is a bit excessive.

Comment: seems to be working, the library is now i386. Thank you!

Comment: @harrymc and StasM, which version of mac you are using? I can't make it work on my Mac 10.8.1. Could you paste your modified brew script here as reference? Thanks.

Comment: @Kane Mine is 10.6.8.

Comment: @StasM, looks like this way doesn't work on mountain lion.

Comment: For completeness the linked article states to do `brew edit <formula>` then to "search for `def install` and, right below, add `ENV['CFLAGS']='xxx'`"

Answer (score 5):

Encountered similar issue installing DevIL. It appears that Homebrew is trying to sanitize commandline parameters passed to tools, at least on ML:

```
$ brew install -v devil
...
brew: superenv removed: -arch i386
...
```

It worked for me to edit the formula like in Walty's answer to specify CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, but run install with a standard environment instead:

```
$ brew install --env=std devil
```

Answer (score 3):

Some Formulas have a universal option that would let you compile for both i386 and x86_64 at the same time:

```
$ brew options sdl
--universal
        Build a universal binary
```

The `mysql-connector-c` doesn't offer it as an option but I found it very easy to add the option to another formula I was working on: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/18713/files